# Spec causes Ruby to crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, crash, specifications

so I'm testing one of my Rails models, but the system's Ruby keeps crashing? This has occurred with Growl before, but never the System's ruby. I've restarted already and it's still occurring. I'm using `Ruby-1.9.3-p194` and the same crash occurs with `ruby-1.9.3-p0`. My spec seems harmless, and I have no idea why this is happening.

**The Spec:**

Sorry about the indentation.

---

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "Admin pages" do
  subject { page}

  describe "when not signed in" do
    before { visit admin_path }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
end

describe "when signed in as an admin" do
before do 
  sign_in 
  visit admin_path
end

describe "Admin navigation menu" do
  it { should have_css('.nav-header', text: 'Content') }
  it { should have_link('Dashboard',  href: admin_path) }
  it { should have_link('News',       href: admin_posts_path) }
  it { should have_link('Events',     href: admin_events_path) }
  it { should have_link('Photos',     href: admin_photos_path) }
  it { should have_css('.nav-header', text: 'Your Account') }
  it { should have_link('Settings',   href: admin_settings_path) }
  it { should have_link('Help',       href: admin_help_path) }

  describe "should be on every admin page" do
    after { should have_admin_navigation }
    it { visit admin_path }
    it { visit admin_posts_path }
    it { visit admin_photos_path }
    it { visit admin_settings_path }
  end


  describe "should not be on any other pages" do
    before { visit root_path }
    it { should_not have_css('#admin-navigation') }
  end

end

describe "Dashboard (index) page" do
  before { visit admin_path }
  it { should have_selector('h3', text: 'Dashboard') }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Admin Dashboard')) }
end

describe "Posts page" do
  before { visit admin_posts_path }
  it { should have_selector('h3', text: 'Posts') }
  it { should have_selector('table') }
  it { should have_selector('th', text: 'Title') }
  it { should have_selector('th', text: 'Content') }
  it { should have_selector('th', text: 'Published On') }
end

describe "Events page" do
  before { visit admin_events_path }
  it { should have_selector('h3', text: 'Events') }
  it { should have_selector('input') }
end

end
end
```

---

[The System Crash Report](https://gist.github.com/aedbf2d61103bb3d7e0c) as a gist to retain formatting.

**EDIT**: I've narrowed it down by commenting and the error has something to do with the `@second_page`'s Factory.

Comment: Does it work when you comment out that test?

Comment: Yep. I commented it out and it passed without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have a debug tool that helps with this. It uses ruby's trace to log all method calls. The last one should be the last call to execute before the crash. Maybe try running this to see what the last method call was before the crash and see if it is consistent? This implementation will slow the app down a lot, FYI, but in a pinch can give you good info.

https://github.com/ericbeland/debugtools/blob/master/tracing.rb

Once you know the method call, you'll hopefully have an idea who/what is responsible.

------- Edited with instructions -----------

Download the linked file (or paste it into a blank file).  Within your app, require the file. Then do the following within application.rb:

```
 include Tracing

 class Object
  include Tracing
 end
```

Find a place within your code that is as late as possible--the last point before which you have never seen it crash. So, based on your new edit, right at the beginning of that test. At that point, paste this statement:

```
 tracing_on('/tmp/tracelog.txt')
```

This will start the logging. Let things run until there's a crash. At that point, look at /tmp/tracelog.txt to see where it died.

Comment: Sorry, how would I go about adding it to my app?

Comment: Sorry, for the late response. The module is still not working. I included it in my `support/` directory, which would allow the module to be available to all specs. I ran the same spec in Ubuntu and got the same result. So, it's not OSX. I'm starting to think that's it's more than the specific spec I posted, so I updated the post with the entire spec. The spec crashes *silently* so I have no idea where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Sorry, I think there has been a misunderstanding. This wasn't a fix, just a way to get a log of what the last command to happen so you can pinpoint what is going on.

Comment: Yeah I know...I realized that I could run `rake` with the trace option enabled to see where it's going wrong. The results were at least not silent, as I got the error: `stack level too deep`. To fix that I added the Webrat gem, and now Rspec is complaining about my custom matcher.

Comment: UPDATE: The webrat gem did not fix the issue.

Comment: Stack level too deep means you are caught in an infinite loop. Look for a method that is calling itself (although it may call some other method or methods first that then call itself again).

Comment: So, by a blessing in disguise I made a major git mistake which reverted me to **way** before the major error occurred and I redid my changes and now my tests are passing...somewhat. As for the Stack level too deep error, I knew that, but the error message was so unhelpful and it referenced three different specs of 250 lines each, which became a major challenge to find. So I guess it worked out in the end! Thanks!

Comment: @ebeland: Thanks, this trace script helped me a lot in a similar situation